# IP migration by filtering

Tags: linux, failover, high-availability, virtual-ip

I'm looking for a solution to use virtual IPs between 2 hosts, but in a specific way. I would like to have the addresses bound to both hosts at once, but filtered out on the inactive one (arp filtering for the routing announcements + traffic filter). I also need to support 2 IPs which have to be bound to 2 interfaces on different networks.

I tried heartbeat - as far as I can tell, it could only bind the IPs themselves via interface aliases.

I tried vrrpd too - it can do the required work just fine, but it seems it doesn't really handle multiple IPs with explicit interfaces, without running 2 copies - and I don't want to end up with the addresses split between the hosts.

Are there any solutions that can help me here? Or can I configure heartbeat to do what I need?